# Did the Robinson's robot ever say this?

Tags: episode-identification, lost-in-space, lost-in-space-1965

I have vague memories of watching the original "Lost in Space" (1965) during its initial run. After re-watching the series recently (broadcast by a local station), I now wonder if one memory I have is actually correct.

The situation is (I believe) Dr. Smith actually doing some work - digging. The robot is standing nearby and says to Smith: "**Less haste, more speed**!".

I've been trying to figure out in which episode the scene occurs... I either missed it while re-watching or it is a faulty memory on my part. I also wonder if the episodes as re-broadcast are the identical edits to what originally aired (would there have been alterations over the years, such as a delete of the scene I believe I remember?).

Answer (score 5):

I dont believe so, but he did say *Less Talk! More Work! ...*

I have yet to find a clip of him saying this line but this link details all [B9 quotes](http://www.danmonroe.com/themagneticlock/phraselist.html).